# How do I trigger off of the ribbonbar being shown/hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ribbon, css

When the ribbon bar is visible (i.e., not in Browse mode), I want certain things to happen on my page (mostly involving changing styles of some items). How do I determine if it's visible or not or trigger off the event that the user changed the display state of it?

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this. Take a look at [this](http://sharepointtaproom.com/2010/07/27/sharepoint-2010-ribbon-responding-to-tab-clicks/)

```
$('#s4-ribbonrow').click(function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).hasClass('ms-cui-tt-span')) {
            if($(e.target).html() == 'Browse')
               alert('browse')
            if(RibbonIsMinimized()) {
               alert($(e.target).html());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Link is dead. Here's the content (via archive.org): https://web.archive.org/web/20120205203124/http://sharepointtaproom.com/2010/07/27/sharepoint-2010-ribbon-responding-to-tab-clicks